# SELECT * FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ... LEFT JOIN T3 ... WHERE T3.KEY NOT IN (1,2,3)

Tags: sql

My application generates the following SQL-request to get the records matching **teamkey**:

```
select cr.callid, t.teamname, u.userfirstname 
from callrecord cr
left join agentrecord ar on cr.callid = ar.callid
left join users u on ar.agentkey = u.userkey 
left join teams t on u.teamkey = t.teamkey 
where t.teamkey in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
```

This works fine.

When I tried to get the records NOT matching **teamkey**, the first idea was:

```
select cr.callid, t.teamname, u.userfirstname 
from callrecord cr
left join agentrecord ar on cr.callid = ar.callid
left join users u on ar.agentkey = u.userkey 
left join teams t on u.teamkey = t.teamkey 
where t.teamkey not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
```

This returns no data. Seems this requires completely different SQL request.
Please help to switch my mind in proper direction.

Record from **callrecord** table may have no matching record in **agentrecord** table, also record from **users** table may have no matching record in **teams** table, but I want them in the output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is turning all those outer joins into inner joins

Comment: Your query is malformed. All those `LEFT JOIN` are silently converted into `INNER JOIN` by the engine since you added a `WHERE` predicate that doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: Request is generated by application with user-controlled filter for teams:
OFF - there will be no **where** clause at all;
INCLUDE - where t.teamkey in (<set_of_teamkeys>);
EXCLUDE - where t.teamkey not in (<set_of_teamkeys>).
For my mind it's OK that left join is converted to inner join in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should work, for example a team key of 17 should be returned.

The condition is not exactly the negation of the original because in SQL `null` values never compare as `true` (look up SQL three-valued logic, they evaluate as `unknown`).
Only `is null` and `is distinct from` (standard but not supported by most RDBMS) can be used to compare nulls.

So the only rows you might be missing are those that don't have a team. If `teamkey` is null (in the table or because one of the join did not match), it would not be returned.

You can get those results back by changing your condition to `t.teamkey not in (...) or t.teamkey is null`